# Responsive Menu Display

Tags: css

First time posting on Stack Overflow.

Wondering if someone could guide me in the right direction re a responsive menu I'm modifying for a website. I figure a demo is the best way to explain and it's [here](http://cdn.tutsplus.com/webdesign/uploads/legacy/tuts/378_tessa/tessa-lt-dropdowns-21c7868/index.html).

When collapsed to mobile size it shows only a gray menu box which clicked on reveals the menu. What I'd like is that display to be the same case at full size. In other words, instead of the horizontal bar with the categories I want there just to be that gray box so when clicked it shows the vertical menu of mobile size (of course, at larger I would make the menu a bit wider). I thought that replacing some of the regular CSS with what was in the media-query would do it but the results have been squirrelly. :D

I hope I've explained this right.

Comment: Have you considered using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of usability, I recommend against making the desktop version behave like the mobile version. Your site becomes harder to use if you act like real estate on a desktop is as limited as it is on a smartphone.

I definitely recommend that, when you have the space to show something, show it.
See [Nielsen Norman Group: Killing off the Global Navigation: One Trend to Avoid](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/killing-global-navigation-one-trend-avoid/).

Answer (score 0):

There are so many frameworks doing this.

You can use Bootstrap navbar:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the condition for screen width in your `script.js` (**`adjustMenu`** function), it should look like this -

```
var adjustMenu = function() {
   $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "inline-block");
       if (!$(".toggleMenu").hasClass("active")) {
          $(".nav").hide();
       } else {
          $(".nav").show();
       }
       $(".nav li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
       $(".nav li a.parent").unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
       // must be attached to anchor element to prevent bubbling
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).parent("li").toggleClass("hover");
   });
}
```

**EDIT: Updated fiddle**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k0aLj1y4/2/) (Expand the result frame)

Comment: Since I've just started posting in SO, please excuse that I'm not answering in the right places. Just getting the hang of what goes where. :D

Comment: Is this the result you expected?

Comment: Ramis - Thank you, will get back to you later on the result. As it stands now I have to leave  to do non-internet things that take stave off the onslaught of the mundane, i.e., regular stuff that keeps me off the streets. :D

Comment: Ramis - You did seem to get the box to open and close at larger but the dropdowns are not showing at either hover or click. Also, at larger I would like it to look like the straight vertical of menu size rather than the bar appearing.

Comment: Ramis - Excellent! May divine camels carry you comfortably across the sands of time. :D And thanks to all the others who took the time to respond.

Comment: Ramis - send me a note to 37power-gmail-com to send you link to site menu will be on.